# Python 3.5 Mac OSX module import

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to add the module telepot to Python 3.5 on my Mac, but i can't find the folder where the python files are.

I tried the  Library/Python folder, but it didn't work because it only had python 2.6 and 2.7 versions in it, i tried creating a folder there but it still didn't work , how can i add the module?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Follow [the instructions](https://github.com/nickoala/telepot#installation) for telepot. Depending how you have setup Python 3.5 on your machine, it may be done different. I am guessing you could write:

```
pip3 install telepot
```

or:

```
sudo pip3 install telepot
```

If you have a VirtualEnv setup, it might just be

```
pip install telepot
```

or:

```
sudo pip install telepot
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on my Mac, do you have a directory of python3?

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wheel/tool
```

Comment: i looked around the usr folder but all i could find was python 2.6 and 2.7

Comment: @AlexS could you please try  __locate python3__ on your terminal?

Comment: I have found the python 3.5 folder, it is located in Library/Frameworks/Python.framework, after opening this, in which folder should i copy the module?

Comment: @ AlexS I would recommend you use pip3 install telepot as the answer following